# Error "Server default repository destination XXXX is invalid" when running application JAR

Tags: java, jar, sap-erp, idoc, sapjco3

We have a Java project made with DropWizard that uses the libraries SAP JCO and SAP IDOC, when run from the IDE it doesn't throw any error, but when it is packaged into a jar and we try to run the jar we receive the following stack trace:

```
com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Server default repository destination AGENT is invalid: Destination AGENT could not be created: java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServer.update(DefaultServer.java:240)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServer.<init>(DefaultServer.java:117)
        at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServer.<init>(DefaultJCoIDocServer.java:47)
        at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServerFactory.createServer(DefaultJCoIDocServerFactory.java:17)
        at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServerFactory.createServer(DefaultJCoIDocServerFactory.java:13)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerManager.getServer(DefaultServerManager.java:104)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.update(StandaloneServerFactory.java:362)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.getServerInstance(StandaloneServerFactory.java:175)
        at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDoc.getServer(JCoIDoc.java:301)
        at com.enapsys.dw.bundles.sapidoc.api.SAPIdocServerListener.run(SAPIdocServerListener.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Destination AGENT could not be created: java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.update(DefaultDestinationManager.java:219)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.searchDestination(DefaultDestinationManager.java:383)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.getDestinationInstance(DefaultDestinationManager.java:99)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:104)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServer.update(DefaultServer.java:218)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
        at com.sap.conn.jco.util.Codecs$AES.generateSecretKey(Codecs.java:1020)
        at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.GUID.<clinit>(GUID.java:62)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntime.createSecureString(JCoRuntime.java:1344)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.checkAndCopyProperties(DefaultDestinationManager.java:549)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.getProperties(DefaultDestinationManager.java:345)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultDestinationManager.update(DefaultDestinationManager.java:171)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.util.Codecs$AES.generateSecretKey(Codecs.java:1015)
        ... 21 more
```

Our .jcoServer file looks like this:

```
jco.server.progid=AGENT
jco.server.name=MYSERVER
jco.server.gwhost=xx.xx.xx.xx
jco.server.gwserv=xxxx
jco.server.connection_count=1
jco.server.repository_destination=AGENT
```

Our .jcoDestination file looks like this:

```
jco.client.type=3
jco.client.client=001
jco.client.user=xxxxxx
jco.client.passwd=xxxxxx
jco.client.lang=en
jco.client.ashost=xxxxxxxx
jco.client.sysnr=00
jco.client.trace=0
jco.destination.repository_destination=AGENT
```

When we run the jar, we do it like this:

```
java -jar -Djava.ext.dirs=lib agent.jar server applicationConfiguration.yml
```

The destination and server share the same program id since our Java application sends and receives iDocs from ERP, we use IntelliJ as an IDE and running the application from there doesn't throw any error and works as expected.

Is there a known cause for this issue? When running the jar outside an IDE, does it need an specific parameter to run? How does the **Destination AGENT could not be created** message relate to the **NoSuchAlgorithmException** error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting **`java.ext.dirs` broke Java crypto**, because (most) providers are in extension jars.

'Add to app' jars *should* be in classpath (but with `-jar` they have to be set in the manifest not the commandline) and 'add to system' jars should normally be put (copied or symlinked) in one of the JVM's standard locations [which vary by platform and install](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html#installed). If you really must use your own directory in `ext.dirs` you need to *add to* not replace the platform-dependent default.

Comment: we placed in the folder lib the sapjco and sapidoc libraries, which we were told we couldn't not distribute inside our jar, so how should we proceed with this? do we have to add a reference to the manifest or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to remark, our project dependencies are handled with Maven, so that could also be part of the problem?

Comment: @UrielArvizu: if you want to run your app 'everywhere' then installing with the app and putting their relative paths in Class-path: in the manifest is the official way. I don't know maven and how it generates the manifest; I'd expect it's in the doc and there might already be a Q on it. If you only want to run on one or a few machine(s) and you have access and the lib jars don't change too much it would be reasonable to put them in the JRE or 'site' dir per my link, and then they are 'automatically' available to all apps.